# How many settlers can be assigned to a single settlement resource?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, when you are building a settlement, how many settlers can you assign to a single resource through the workshop? For example, if I have 6 corn plants, how many settlers would I need to assign to those to make sure they're all covered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One settler per resource with the exception of food, one worker can work "six" food, for example 12 foods that give 0.5 food each or 6 mutifruit trees (giving 1 each) or any combination of food producing resources as long its only 6 food total. In the instance of food [you don't have to assign them manually to each subsequent crop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243902/52800).

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is a standard settler. Unique settlers have different 'effort values'.

Comment: Is there a way to tell what those effort values are?